# Problem sets for Griffith and Harris?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Are there any problem sets floating around that correspond to the material in Griffiths and Harris' "Principles of Algebraic Geometry"?  I find a good set of problems helps cement the concepts when I'm first learning the material.

Comment: For the early chapters I think Huybrechts' _Complex Geometry_ covers a lot of the same ground in more detail and has exercises for each section; it's worth skimming, at least. But there's a crazy amount of stuff in G&H.

Comment: There is, though I only expect problems from the chapter 0-2, and maybe parts of 3 and 4. I'll certainly check out Huybrechts. Thanks for that.